# Adonisjs How to cast boolean to false and true in a model instead of 0 or 1?

Tags: javascript, mysql, adonis.js, lucid, adonisjs-ace

**This is my table field (open) but in response, it returns 0 1 but I want true false instead of 0 1**

*I am using adonis  MySQL*

*table.boolean('open').notNullable().defaultTo(true).comment('true = open, false = close')*

const Model = use('Model')

```
class Markup extends Model {
static boot() {
    super.boot()

    this.addTrait('@provider:Lucid/SoftDeletes')
    
}
static getColumns() {
    return ['assignee_id', 'editor_details', 'visibility', 'image_url', 'priority', 'open']
}
comments() {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/Comment', 'id', 'markup_id')
}

assignee() {
    return this.belongsTo("App/Models/User", "assignee_id", "id")
}
created_by() {
    return this.belongsTo("App/Models/User", 'created_by_id', 'id')
}
resolved_by() {
    return this.belongsTo("App/Models/User", 'resolved_by_id', 'id')
}
```

}

module.exports = Markup

Comment: Boolean isn't a distinct datatype in MySQL; it's just a synonym for tinyint. what you can do is write an after hook in your model to convert 1/0 to true/false.

Comment: Hello @Muhammad
Did you get the answer? I need it pls.

Answer (score 2):

This just a simple fix.
you just have to do this in your column.

```
@column({ serialize: Boolean })
```

Answer (score -1):

As @asad-jivani said:

> Boolean isn't a distinct datatype in MySQL; it's just a synonym for tinyint. what you can do is write an after hook in your model to convert 1/0 to true/false.

In these cases I use a property of laravel/lumen calls $casts, this is specified in the model.

here is an example without the $cast to is_draft field.

JSON Response:

```json
{
    "areas": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "is_draft": 1,
            "title": "Example"
        }
    ]
}
```

to convert the filed is_draft to true or false I just added this in my model.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Area extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $table = 'areas';

    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $casts = [
        'is_draft' => 'boolean',
    ];
}
```

and here is the parsed JSON Response:

```json
{
    "areas": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "is_draft": true,
            "title": "Example"
        }
    ]
}
```

I hope this helps you